# Comment Pagination

Tags: comments, pagination

I am hoping someone can help me with comments pagination. I have the pagination working and the links point to the next page etc, but when clicking the page just refreshes. Here is my code so far and hoping someone can help me.

```
$pid = $post->ID;   
$comment_query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_comments` WHERE comment_post_ID = ".$pid. " AND comment_approved = '1'";
$comments_array = $wpdb->get_results($comment_query, OBJECT);

if ($comments_array): 
                                                $cpp = 10; // Comments per page
                                                 $wp_query->comments = count($comments_array);
                                                 //echo $wp_query->found_posts;
                                                 $wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->comments / $cpp);
                                                 $on_page = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
                                                 if($on_page == 0){ $on_page = 1; } 
                                                 $offset = ($on_page-1) * $cpp;
                                                 $wp_query->request = "
                                                SELECT * FROM `wp_comments` WHERE comment_post_ID = ".$pid. " AND comment_approved = '1'                                            
                                                LIMIT $cpp
                                                OFFSET $offset
                                                    ";
                                                $newcomments = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request, OBJECT);
?>                                      
<div class="comments">
    <?php if ($newcomments) : ?>
        <a name="comments" id="comment_anchor"></a>
        <h3 class="section-title"><?php _(comments_number('No <span>Comments</span>','1 <span>Comment</span>','% <span>Comments</span>')); ?></h3>
        <ul class="comment-container">
            <?php 

                foreach ($newcomments as $comment) :
```

full code: http://pastebin.com/md3zdpbd

Thanks

Comment: I added the formatting, but please care about the code style. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy function a.k.a. template tag for that called [`paginate_comments_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/paginate_comments_links)